# Find unique text in word doc and copy consecutive string from this word doc, from excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, automation, binding, ms-word

My goal is to find unique text in the word document "The economies of Northern Ireland " and copy three consecutive words from this document. And I have to do this from excel VBA.
The word document being searched, will be manually opened before VBA code is executed from .xlsm file.
It's going to be the only opened .docx file at the time of VBA code execution, but the file name will always be different, therefore we cannot hardcode the .docx file name nor path.

```
Sub Find_Price()

    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim TextToFind As String
    Dim NumberToFind As String
    Dim Rng As Word.Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'This is the text I'm looking for in .ActiveDocument
    TextToFind = "The economies of Northern Ireland "
    NumberToFind = "82110907192"
    'Reference already opened Word document from excel VBA console
    Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    WordApp.Application.Visible = True
    WordDoc.Select
    Set Rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
    'Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FilePath & "Form1.docx")
    'Set WordDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument     'I don't know how to finish this line  :-(
        'With WordApp.Content.Find.Execute.NumberToFind
        With WordDoc.Content.Find.Execute.NumberToFind     'Code crashes in this line;
        Rng.Find.Execute FindText:=TextToFind, Forward:=True
                'what this "Forward:=True" means??
        If Rng.Find.Found Then
            If Rng.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
               ' I don't know how to write this part of the code.
               ' Please don't remove my question again - I've researched 16h for this info.
               MsgBox "Price is " & TextToFind & " pln."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Text was not found!"
        End If
End Sub
```

The code crashes on this line:

```
With WordDoc.Content.Find.Execute.NumberToFind
```

[image]

Most important thing for me is to:

1) perform a search on currently opened word doc, from excel vba editor,

2) find unique text = "The economies of Northern Ireland " in this word document,

3) and copy this text to a clipboard, so I could manually paste it into the cell of my choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search the range.

```vb
With Rng.Find
    .Text = "The economies of Northern Ireland "
    .Execute
    If .Found = True Then
        Rng.MoveEnd wdWord, 3
        Rng.Copy
    Else
        MsgBox "Not found"
    End If
End With
```

If the word document is already open (and you're sure it will be open every time) then I'd just lazily declare variables.

```vb
Dim oDoc as Word.Document
Set oDoc = Word.ActiveDocument
Dim oRng as Word.Range
Set oRng = oDoc.Content
```

But that's my personal opinion.

Comment: Is this line correct?
```Set Rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content```

Comment: Is this line correct?
```Set Rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content```
I got an error "Object variable or With block variable not set" - run time error 91.
This is my code before your solution.
```Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim TextToFind As String
Dim NumberToFind As String
Dim Rng As Word.Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
TextToFind = "The economies of Northern Ireland "
NumberToFind = "82110907192"
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
WordApp.Application.Visible = True
WordDoc.Select
Set Rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
```

Comment: Yes. When you search a range, if the text is found, the range is altered to only be the found text. So you can just loop through the document, as it will return only the found range accordingly. See my edit for variable assignments.

Comment: The WordApp is set here:
```
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
```
Do I need to Set WordDoc somehow? Somewhere?
I still have "Object variable or With block variable not set" - run time error 91 around here somewhere when I debug the code:
```
WordDoc.Select
Set Rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content
```

Comment: Delete `WordDoc.Select`, you don't have it set to anything and you don't need to. You're already `Set Rng = WordApp.ActiveDocument.Content` so there's no reason to do `Set WordDoc = WordApp.ActiveDocument`. It's clear that you're learning, so you've got a lot of attempts in your code. At this point, it's worth your time to start over with what you've learned here.

Comment: Do you suggest that this line is redundant: ```Dim WordApp As Word.Application```.
And whole ```WordApp``` variable declaration is unnecessary to run this macro?

Comment: Up to you. See my answer for a lazy way to do it (and my preferred way). It's preference. I'm sure it's probably safer to do `Dim oWrd as Object: Set oWrd = CreateObject("Word.Application")` and then go from there but if you know the document will be open then it's not necessary.